# Error con reCaptcha de google PHP

Tags: php

estoy colocando el reCaptcha en mi formulario de contacto pero cada ves que lo envio me regresa el FALSE:

```
    $google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    $secret='xxxxxxxx';
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = $google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recap."&remoteip=".$ip;
    $res = json_decode($url);
    //reCaptcha success check
    if($res['success']){
        echo true;  
    }else{
        echo false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con este código:

1) Declara el script en la página

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es" async defer></script>
```

2) Realiza un include

require_once "includes/recaptchalib.php";

3) Validas el captcha

```
 $secret = "6Le_AyoTA7777777Abv56kY6w_fcPMwEqL";
 $response = null;
 // comprueba la clave secreta
 $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

 if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
     $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
     $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
     $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
     );
  }


 if ($response != null &amp;&amp; $response->success) {
    // OK Captcha
  } else {
    // Error Captcha
  }
```

Para crear tu propia clave secreta accede al siguiente link:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

Comment: si tengo mi propia clave... pero que va en el /recaptchalib.php? gracias !

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest

Comment: de ahi descargate el archivo amigo